# What file compression has a header/signature 78 56 34

Tags: compression

I've got a compressed file. I don't know what compression software was used to create it. I want to decompress it, preferably on a Windows platform. The file extension is .CMP but that may just be a "cute" extension name and not really be indicative of what was used to create it.

The file header (starting bytes): 78 56 34. I've searched for that and it comes up as "PhotoCap Template". I can't seem to find any information about that format, yet alone a way to decompress such a file. The uncompressed data has nothing to do with photos/graphics. I tried using 7-Zip but it doesn't recognize the file compression.

Other ideas?
Bill

Comment: Is that in hex or decimal?

Comment: D'oh! Those are hex bytes. Following those 3 bytes are a 1-byte "length of filename that follows", followed by the original filename.